# Unexpected character shows up after writing to csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, encoding, character-encoding

I have being using PyCharm to clean my training set for ML.

Long story short, the string I stored is different from what I saw in the debugger watcher.

Is it an encoding problem? How can I get it right?

debugger:

[image]

real csv:

[image]

I load the csv file with and split the column by:

```
    train_set_x = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    index, text = zip(*((c[0], c[1]) for c in train_set_x))
```

This is really troubling me since I have to strip all question marks later. And once I have done the striping and store the string back to another csv, the question marks are still there.

BTW, this is the code I used for striping:

```
entry = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha,entry))
```

( "entry" is an element of 1D numpy array array, converted from "text" above)

I have tried every encoding readily provided by notepad ++ and no good.

---

#### Solved

The problem is that I loaded the file with encoding "utf-8" and did not write it with such encoding. The problem has been solved by writing the file with encoding "utf-8".

Comment: This is a character encoding problem. Are you sure you're using UTF-8 all the way?

Comment: How did you open your file? `with open(..., encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ YES! is it the problem?

Comment: Possibly.. change the encoding to `latin-1` and see what happens.